# find the reason of PC power off

Tags: logs, var

Today i had powered on my PC, and it powered off few times, while power-on workflow.

I had check in log, but didn't find the reason,  I had  powered it on about 14:00 or near, (few times until was successfully powered it on).

The excidental power off was happened at the various moments: after system loaded and GRUB menu on screen or after password was entered and X-Window manager loaded, and old browser session restarted, or when new internet page started to open.

Then it continued to work until now.

in a listing below it show few lines after 14:13 boot, and few lines before the new boot in 14:19, it works about 6  min before exidental power-off so it may concluded the reasons, but i'm has not find  error messages like

: because of ...  reason PC power-off or smth else.

I had read man journalctl, just i don't know, what subject i need to find?

**How to find the proper exidental power-off  reason ?**

Below i had listed the log from first power on today which has included all shorts periods in a start and normal workflow until evening

> sudo journalctl -S "today" -U "17:00"

```
 ov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd[1]: Reached target shutdown.target - System Shutdown.
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd[1]: Reached target final.target - Late Shutdown Services.
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd[1]: Finished systemd-poweroff.service - System Power Off.
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd[1]: Reached target poweroff.target - System Power Off.
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd-journald[258]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
Nov 04 04:40:26 debian systemd-journald[258]: Journal stopped
-- Boot 5e8abe8207f54af483786970a32bfdb1 --
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x22, date = 2022-0>
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: Linux version 6.1.0-13-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc>
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-13-amd64 root=UUID=a4>
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009b3ff] usable
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009b400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000000fffffff] usable
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000010000000-0x0000000012150fff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000012151000-0x00000000771abfff] usable
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000771ac000-0x0000000079a73fff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000079a74000-0x0000000079aadfff] ACPI data
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000079aae000-0x0000000079e7cfff] ACPI NVS
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000079e7d000-0x000000007a23dfff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a23e000-0x000000007aa2cfff] usable
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007aa2d000-0x000000007aa2dfff] ACPI NVS
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007aa2e000-0x000000007aa2ffff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007aa30000-0x000000007aae4fff] usable
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007aae5000-0x000000007ab94fff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ab95000-0x000000007affffff] usable
Nov 04 14:13:53 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007b000000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
Nov 04 14:13:53 d
```

this is the lines before the next boot, so it's may be concluded the power-off reason, but i don't understand, which?
There aren't any error messages

```
   ov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Finished systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel >
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: systemd-firstboot.service - First Boot Wizard was skipped beca>
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: systemd-pstore.service - Platform Persistent Storage Archival >
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Starting systemd-random-seed.service - Load/Save Random Seed...
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Starting systemd-sysusers.service - Create System Users...
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian kernel: lp: driver loaded but no devices found
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian kernel: ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Finished systemd-random-seed.service - Load/Save Random Seed.
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: first-boot-complete.target - First Boot Complete was skipped b>
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Finished systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules.
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Starting systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables...
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Finished systemd-sysusers.service - Create System Users.
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Starting systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service - Create Static De>
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Finished systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables.
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd-journald[259]: Journal started
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd-journald[259]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/337f99dad83d4d2fb>
Nov 04 14:17:53 debian systemd-modules-load[261]: Inserted module 'lp'
Nov 04 14:17:53 debian systemd-modules-load[261]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Nov 04 14:17:53 debian systemd-modules-load[261]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Started systemd-journald.service - Journal Service.
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Starting systemd-journal-flush.service - Flush Journal to Pers>
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service - Create Static De>
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd[1]: Starting systemd-udevd.service - Rule-based Manager for Device>
Nov 04 14:17:54 debian systemd-journald[259]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/337f99da>
-- Boot 59ee50dd793649a3b9022074301768ee --
ov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x22, date = 2022-0>
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: Linux version 6.1.0-13-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc>
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-13-amd64 root=UUID=a4>
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009b3ff] usable
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009b400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000000fffffff] usable
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000010000000-0x0000000012150fff] reserved
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000012151000-0x00000000771abfff] usable
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000771ac000-0x0000000079a73fff] reserved
Nov 04 14:19:07 debian kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000079a74000-0x0000000079aadfff] ACPI data


BIOS Information
Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
Version: 5.13
Release Date: 10/19/2020
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 5 MB
Characteristics:
    PCI is supported
    BIOS is upgradeable
    BIOS shadowing is allowed
    Boot from CD is supported
    Selectable boot is supported
    BIOS ROM is socketed
    EDD is supported
    5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
    8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
    Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Printer services are supported (int 17h)
    ACPI is supported
    USB legacy is supported
    BIOS boot specification is supported
    Targeted content distribution is supported
    UEFI is supported
BIOS Revision: 5.13
```

Comment: `line 1-33` means it is only showing you lines 1-33.  It is waiting for interaction before it shows you the rest.  Use the "down" arrow to scroll down, use `--no-pager` to print everything at once to the screen, or use `> tmp.log` to redirect the log into a file that you can read at your discretion.

Comment: Does it power down suddenly or after going through a graceful shutdown? Could be overheat or PSU or other hardware failure if the former.

Comment: it power down suddenly 5 or 11 times at the initial part only, from 14:13 till 14:27, for example, then it can continue to work up to 23:30 or till 04:05 the next day.

Comment: During boot, the system is very busy and tends to "stress" most components of the system as it initialises them. The point here is to figure out what is stressed to the point of causing an emergency poweroff. Most likely culprit is the CPU. Does doing `xz -T0 < /dev/zero > /dev/null` (an easy way to stress all cores of all CPUs) cause a poweroff for instance?

Comment: Does your computer have a serial port to which you could connect a terminal for console output? Or a base management controller (as typical of servers)?

Comment: Does your BIOS / firmware have diagnostics utilities which you can invoke at boot time (by pressing Del / F2 / F10 / F12 depending on model)?

Comment: I concur with Stéphane. Each time I have encountered such a problem, this was due to CPU cooling issue. Check that your CPU fan is spinning and/or replace the thermal paste between the CPU and its heatsink.

Comment: xhienne 
i had replaced thermal paste 2 month ago, and returned the fan back (i had checked, can it work in a funless mode (it has a big heat sink inside a body))  and the result was that before replacement the excidental power off can be happened while a normal workflow, and now power off is in a start period only, if it passed restart old session in browser download, then it work up to the manual shutdown.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas
lm@debian:~$ xz -T0 < /dev/zero > /dev/null stephane, nothing was happened after i enter this command.

      `lm@debian:~$ xz -T0 < /dev/zero > /dev/null`

      `q `

       `q`
but it had'nt any screen output, I interrupt it after 10 min by ctrl-c command

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas my PC has USB only, and ETH0 and wifi0, and it can be attached to my phone as wifi router as server? my display connected by hdmi interface. Of coarse, i have another PC, which i can use.

Comment: `xz -T0 < /dev/zero > /dev/null` compresses `/dev/zero` in parallel and sends the output to `/dev/null`, it's meant to stress the CPUs. You'd let it run long enough for the system to get hot.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas
of coarse, it has bios diagnostic
      i had edit main topic for the Bios info

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas i had use it from 15:54 till 16:49 and it continue to work, but the metal body (it''s connected to the heat sink ) is warm now +42C (it never becomes to reach this temperature as usual)

Comment: i had checked it up to 21, so it's work while 5 hrs +41.5C